# How to open a pkl file which has been trained on a OpenAI Gym game with reinforcement learning

Tags: python, pickle, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to follow karpathy's article on Reinforcement learning with Pong : http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/

Here is his code : [Github](https://gist.github.com/karpathy/a4166c7fe253700972fcbc77e4ea32c5)

At line 126 you can see that his trained model is being dumped to 'save.p' file.

Now, how do I open this pkl file so that I can watch how good the bot is performing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `render = True` on line 13 to see the agent training.

If you want to check the performance after training (evaluation) then you can comment out the update part of the model which starts at line 116 and set `resume = True` on line 12.

Hope this helps